# Special characters not recognize from Google Sheet & Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets, utf-8

I have developed a web crawler to extract some information and print them to an Excel spreadsheet.

However, neither Excel nor Google Sheet recognize some  special characters, see below:

[image: Special characters]

The text should be the following: *("Woodland"​ or the "Company"​)*
This is just a case, there are several more special characters not recognized.

Do you know how I can convert them? Do I have to turn on some feature on Excel and Google Sheet?

I have been stuck on it for days - any help is welcomed.

Thank you!!

Comment: It would help if you explain how you get this text and how you store it in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

What is the crawler written in? The easiest option would probably be to have the parser take out special characters before output.

That said, how are you outputting data to the spreadsheets themselves? I think we need more info to help you here.

Alternatively you could use something like this 
https://exceljet.net/formula/remove-unwanted-characters

Answer (score 0):

Excel does support Unicode. Your (unspecified) method and encoding is to blame.

This looks like you are retrieving data from the Web in UTF-8 format, then
importing it to Excel without specifying the UTF-8 encoding, so it thinks
it is reading ANSI text.
The result is that special characters in UTF-8 that take two bytes
are displayed as two weird characters.

If you are creating an input file for Excel, you could preface it with a
[Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
The UTF-8 representation of the BOM is the (hexadecimal) byte sequence
`0xEF,0xBB,0xBF`.